# Border on selected series in Stacked Bar charts + High Charts

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

I am using High charts for rendering Stacked Bar charts.

How to get the border on a **Stacked Bar Chart** when the user clicks on a particular series?? I tried **marker** option but that is selecting only one series, but I want the complete series to be selected.

Currently I am getting like this:-

[image]

But, I want like this:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use renderer to add such rect in the background: http://jsfiddle.net/3Utat/25/

```
    mouseOver: function () {
        var chart = this.series.chart,
            r = chart.renderer,
            shape = this.shapeArgs, // shape args for the points rect element
            xAxis = this.series.xAxis,
            yAxis = this.series.yAxis,
            y = yAxis.toPixels(this.total), // top left y-position of the rect
            x = this.plotX + chart.plotLeft - shape.width / 2, // point position + left offset + half width
            height = yAxis.toPixels(yAxis.min) - y; // bottom - top

        if (chart.hoverStack) {
            chart.hoverStack.destroy();
        }

        chart.hoverStack = r.rect(x, y, shape.width, height).attr({
                'stroke-width': 6, //border width
                'stroke': 'black', //border color
                'fill': 'transparent' //transparent fill color
        }).add();

    },
    mouseOut: function () {
        if (this.series.chart.hoverStack) {
            this.series.chart.hoverStack.destroy();
            this.series.chart.hoverStack = false;
        }
    }
```

Example is using `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events, but in your case, you can use `click` event instead.

Comment: Waoo, I reall y thank u for your answer. This really solved my problem.Although, it will take a bit to understand what you have done. I will ask you if I find difficulty in understanding....Thanks Again!!!

Comment: I guessed so, that's why code in the answer is quite commented ;) The rest comes from official API (toPixels, destroy, rect, attr, add, etc. methods).

Comment: @Pawel..I have not tried yet..,just asking, this can be done for Stacked bar chart also with some tweaks?

Comment: Can you please tell from where I can understand plotX,plotLeft and other values used there? I checked the HighCharts API reference but not able to find those..as I need the behavior for Stacked Bar Chart...

Comment: @Pawel..Can you please give the same for Stacked Bar Chart. I am not able to get the meaning of plotX/plotLeft etc..

Comment: Sure, `plotX` -> x-position for the column. `plotLeft`-> distance between left border of the container and plotting area. Note: in the bar chart, it's harder to position that items because of rotation. I made example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3Utat/26/ - sorry, I missed in the questions somehow that you need bar chart, not column chart.

Comment: you are just superb..Thank u a lot!!!.. I will go through this code and will try to grab as much as I can, but I will require your help if I am stuck somewhere...Thanks Again!!! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pawel, The correct Fiddle for Border on selected 
**Stacked Bar Chart** is :-

http://jsfiddle.net/3Utat/26/

```
click: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart,
                            r = chart.renderer,
                            shape = this.shapeArgs,
                            xAxis = this.series.xAxis,
                            yAxis = this.series.yAxis,
                            y = yAxis.toPixels(this.total),
                            x = this.plotX - shape.width / 2,
                            height = Math.abs(yAxis.toPixels(yAxis.min) - y);

                        if (chart.hoverStack) {
                            chart.hoverStack.destroy();
                        }

                        chart.hoverStack = r.rect(x, chart.plotWidth+chart.plotLeft-y, shape.width, height).attr({
                            'stroke-width': 6,
                                'stroke': 'black',
                            fill: 'transparent',
                            transform: 'translate(' + (chart.plotWidth+chart.plotLeft) + ' ' +  (chart.plotHeight+chart.plotTop) + ' ) rotate(90) scale(-1,1)'
                        }).add();

                    }
```